# How to subtract specific fields in a row from 2 dates in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table where the data updates every hour and I need to subtract the number of quantities as of today and what was 60 days back. How can that be done in SQL?

Comment: What database do you use ? What columns does this table have ?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: @VBoka I am using Amazon Redshift database. I have a column which has the date and time column which updates daily and a quantity of sales column. I need to subtract the quantity as on today and of 2 months back.